# Can I run React Native code inside the Ionic Angular project?

Tags: angular, react-native, ionic-framework

i have an ionic angular project and I need to add some code of ionic react native inside the ionic angular project. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a [capacitor](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native) plugin to achieve it.